# SQL- Query to select data using date selected using datepicker

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get data from database based on date selected using datepicker.

I am using the following query to get data between selected dated but what i need is like when i select `from_date` and `to_date` using datepicker and click a button i want all the data assocoated with the selected date to be displayed. What change should i make in the query (I think after **Between**). Someone please help me. Thanks in advance. I want to use this with PHP as a server page.

```
SELECT
  EP.Employee_Id,
  TD.Training_Id,
  TD.Training_Date,
  DT.Topic_Name,
  EP.Employee_Name
FROM
  `training_details` TD 
  INNER JOIN `domain_topics` DT ON DT.Domain_Id=TD.Domain_Id 
  INNER JOIN `trainer_details` TRD ON TRD.Training_Id = TD.Training_Id
  INNER JOIN `employee_profile` EP ON TRD.Trainer_Id = EP.Employee_Id
WHERE
  TD.Training_Date BETWEEN '2012-12-01' AND '2012-12-31';
```

Comment: so you want 2012-12-31 records included in the result? actually your question is hard to understand

Comment: Pass the `from_date` and `to_date` selected variable dates to the query you posted instead of the literal dates.

Comment: sorry about that..let me explain..i have a query(which i have mentioned in the question) which retrieves some data from database based on the date given.What i need is to change the query such that i can get the data when i select the date in the front end.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I didnt get you. how can i do with the php file i have.?

Comment: @Midhun - You have to edit your question explaining that you are looking for doing this using PHP and tag it with php

Comment: ok..i will do that @MahmoudGamal

Comment: What is the data type for the field Training_Date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help: If you are using **POST** method:

```
SELECT  EP.Employee_Id, TD.Training_Id, TD.Training_Date, DT.Topic_Name, EP.Employee_Name 
FROM `training_details` TD
INNER JOIN `domain_topics` DT ON DT.Domain_Id=TD.Domain_Id 
INNER JOIN `trainer_details` TRD ON TRD.Training_Id = TD.Training_Id
INNER JOIN `employee_profile` EP ON TRD.Trainer_Id = EP.Employee_Id
WHERE TD.Training_Date >= '$_POST[from_date]' AND TD.Training_Date <= '$_POST[to_date]';
```

OR as in your query `WHERE` clause be like this:

```
WHERE TD.Training_Date BETWEEN $_POST[from_date] AND $_POST[to_date]
```

If you are using **GET** method, it will be:

```
WHERE TD.Training_Date BETWEEN $_GET[from_date] AND $_GET[to_date]
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. What i need is to change the query such that i can get the data when i select the date in the front end.

Comment: I use PHP in the server side

Comment: what changes should i make to my php file to do with 'get' method

Comment: Change form method attribute to GET ...<form method="get"